# How arrange two tables, one besides the other

Tags: tables

I'm doing a report using LaTeX. I have not too much experience here, and need to solve this issue. It is a simple question:

How can I arrange two tables, one beside the other in LaTeX?

For example:

```
[Table1] [Table2]
```

Comment: Just place the code of one table after the other. By the way, welcome to TX.SX!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------
% No space between the tables
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
test & test\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
test & test\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\par
%----------------------------------------
% Added a space between the tables
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
test & test\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace{2cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
test & test\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%----------------------------------------
% Centered with a space between the tables
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
test & test\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace{2cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
test & test\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Or else in a `minipage`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{}
        \label{tab:first}
        \begin{tabular}{rcl}
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{}
        \label{tab:second}
        \begin{tabular}{rcl}
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note the `%` after the first `\end{minipage}` to prevent the extra space creating an `overfull hbox`.